# git commits on a specific branch

Tags: git

I'm looking for the commits of a specific branch. My tree looks as follows:

```
feature/X     C--E--F
             /       \
master  -A--B--D---G--H--I--J->
```

How to get the commits C,E and F?
What I tried is:

```
git rev-list feature/X ^master
```

but this gives no commits. I assume in that special case the problem is the back merge of feature/X to the master. That's why the commits C, E and F are accessible from master too, isn't it? So - how to handle that situation, Any ideas?

Regards
Thomas

Comment: ```git rev-list sha1_of_B..feature/X```?

Comment: Cool, thanks - that works - but how to identify (automatically) B? To figure this out I have to check which commits of feature/X are accessible an any other reference, isn't it? And - as far as I understand C, E and F are accessible using the master.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, once it's merged, the details of which branch the commit came from is lost. All you have is that the commits are covered by the current branch.

However, I can sort of find a way like so.
First, you find where the merge took place.  This can be done using a `git log --merges -1` to find the nearest merge to master (in your case, `H`) . The `featureX` branch I assume is right behind this at `F`. This commit has 2 parents. Since `featureX` was merged into master, you can get the target branch parent using `H^`.

Then, you can find the difference between `H^` and `F` like so, `git log H^..featureX` which should give you all the commits reachable from `featureX` and omits those reachable from `H^` ie. `C`, `E` and `F`.

As an example, here is a repo.
[image: example]

If done, right, I should get all the "Update X" commits.

First, we get the merge commit.

```
% git log --merges -1 --oneline
e8928b9 Merge branch 'X'
```

Then we get the log in question. The feature branch is called `X` in my repo.

```
% git log e8928\^..X --oneline
92a1f58 Updates x 10
f56306d Updates x 9
54d2253 Updates x 8
a8ba58b Updates x 7
10d08c5 Updates x 6
625d267 Updates x 5
96671d4 Updates x 4
5031498 Updates x 3
41770ea Updates x 2
442033b Updates x 1
```

This is, at best, hackish. I'd be very interested in finding a genuine solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little bit hackish, but working one-liner:

```
git rev-list "$(git rev-list feature/X..master | tail -n 1)^"..feature/X
```

Comment: Thanks - looks if this is my solution. Just for my understanding: What exact does the ^ behind the sha?

Comment: @user3592527 `sha^` means "first parent of `sha`"

Comment: @rudimeier I've changed answer to your version.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to re-draw this:

```
feature/X     C--E--F
             /       \
master  -A--B--D---G--H--I--J->
```

as this:

```
        C--E--F           <-- feature/X
       /       \
<--A--B--D---G--H--I--J   <-- master
```

The reason is that the arrows *really do* point backwards, with `feature/X` pointing to the *tip commit* of branch `feature/X`, i.e., to commit `F`, and `master` pointing to the tip commit of `master` (which I've assumed is `J` here, though maybe there are more given your original drawing).

As you've noted, `feature/X ^master` (which can also be spelled `master..feature/X`) fails because commit `F` is reachable from `master` by starting at the commit to which `master` points (`J`) and working backwards.  When we hit commit `H` we work backwards through both parents simultaneously, so the request to eliminate all commits reachable from `master` also eliminates the `C--E--F` sequence.

To stop that from happening, we must eliminate commits starting from some point before `H`, i.e., a point before the first merge that brings the tip of `feature/X` into `master`.  Any of commits `G`, `D`, or `B` will suffice.  That is, if we had the hash of *any one* of these commits, then:

```
git rev-list feature/X ^$hash
```

would do the trick.

[qzb's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39719754/1256452) finds commit `D` and then uses a suffix `^` to identify its first and only parent.  It works by listing every commit reachable from `J` (the tip of `master`) that is not also reachable from `F` (the tip of `feature/X`).  There is a caveat: `git rev-list` may sort commits, so that `D` may not actually be listed last, but the `| tail -1` assumes that the listing ends with commit `D`'s hash.

This therefore depends on the date-stamps stored in the commits.  If they were made in order (so that the dates all increase as the commits move forward in time), that's not a problem.  Usually they do.  But sometimes you can add commits in the "wrong" date order, due to clocks being set incorrectly, or commits being done on different computers that disagree as to what time it is, or whatever.

We can fix the date assumption by telling `git rev-list` to use `--topo-order`, which forces it to list commits in *graph* order (using a partial order from the graph topology).  So when using this method, add `--topo-order`.

[Noufal Ibrahim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39719604/1256452)'s method works by finding commit `H` instead, using `git log`.  It's a bit better to use `git rev-list`, which takes the same options as `git log` but just prints the hash (which is all we want):

```
H=$(git rev-list --merges -1 master)
# H stands for Hash, and also for "commit H" :-)
```

(note that we must specify a starting point for the graph walk, while `git log` defaults to starting from `HEAD`).  Obtaining the hash for commit `H` is not quite sufficient since we must then climb one parent back.  Since `H` has *two* parents, we must carefully climb from `H` to `G` (not to `F`).

Fortunately, whenever we merge with `git merge`, Git makes sure that the *first* parent of the new merge commit is the commit that was on the current branch.  That is, when we made commit `H` by running `git merge feature/X`, we were on branch `master` and the name `master` meant commit `G`.  So the *first* parent of `H` is `G`, hence `$H^1`, or just `$H^`, identifies commit `G`:

```
H=$(git rev-list --merges -1 master)
git rev-list feature/X ^${H}^
```

The curly braces around `H` are not technically necessary, just meant for clarity: we expand `$H` and then put `^` after the expansion (to identify commit `G`), and another `^` in front of the expansion (to tell `git rev-list` that we're using this as an exclusion specifier).

Since `$yes ^$no` can be written as `$no..$yes` instead, we can also write this as:

```
H=$(git rev-list --merges -1 master)
git rev-list ^${H}^..feature/X
```

This method is a bit more efficient (we enumerate just the one commit `H`, rather than using `tail -1` to get the last commit of some potentially long chain) and does not suffer from date-order issues (but we saw above how to fix those with `--topo-order`).

Incidentally, this too really should use `--topo-order` when finding commit `H`, for the same reason: we don't want Git to sort and put some other merge (something before `A`, for instance) in front of `H`.

#### The remaining flaws

[qzb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5508756/qzb) noted one of them: while `feature/X` points to commit `F`, if there are more merges in the past, we don't necessarily "know where to stop".  That is:

```
          o--o---o--o--o     <-- feature
         /    \ /       \
...--o--o--o---o--o--o---o   <-- master
```

By drawing this particular graph in this particular way, it's clear to *us* that all the commits along the "top line" are those that were done on `feature`, and that `feature` was merged into `master` twice, while `master` was merged back into `feature` once.  (Incidentally this sort of "cross merging" can get you into trouble.  It's not *wrong*, but in general you should be careful about merging A into B and B into A.  In some cases this produces multiple merge bases for merges, which can be tricky.)  But it's not clear to Git, and there are other ways to draw the graph that will obscure it from our own eyes as well.  (Moreover, if you ever allow "fast forward" merges (rather than a non-fast-forward, actual merge commit, merges), untangling branch history becomes impossible in general.  Again, it's not *wrong*, you just need to be prepared to deal with it.)

A more important issue occurs with both methods if there is a merge on `master` past commit `H`.  That is, suppose that the lettered graph we've been drawing so far is still a bit misleading, and in fact it should look like this:

```
        C--E--F           <-- feature/X
       /       \
<--A--B--D---G--H--I--J   <-- master
                  /
         <-o--o--o        <-- feature/Y
```

Now if we do:

```
H=$(git rev-list --topo-order --merges -1 master)
```

we will wind up setting `$H` to point to commit `I`, rather than commit `H`.  The reason is simple: we asked for the most recent (topologically) commit starting from `master` and working backwards, that is also a merge commit.  That's commit `I`.  But `I^` is commit `H` and excluding `H` will make the subsequent `git rev-list` exclude commits `C--E--F`.

That seems to doom this approach; can we go back to locating commit `D`?  No, because qzb's trick:

```
$(git rev-list feature/X..master | tail -n 1)
```

stops working when Git races down the *second* parent of `I`, i.e., through `feature/Y`, and begins listing all *those* commits.  Without `--topo-order`, we get the oldest commit.  With `--topo-order` we are still not told which chain (`I^1` vs `I^2`) is handled first.  If that chain connects back at commit `A` or earlier, we may get the hash for commit `A`-or-earlier, instead of that for commit `D`.

We could fix that by noting the additional merge `I` that brings in `feature/Y`, and excluding `feature/Y` so that Git does *not* race down that chain.  But this begins to get complicated.  What we really need, then, is not the *most recent merge*, but rather *the merge that brings in commit `F`* (i.e., "find me commit `H`").  Is there a way to get that?  As it turns out, there is.  What we want here is `--ancestry-path`.

The `--ancestry-path` option strips out commits that are *not* descendants of an excluded commit.  Since `feature/X` is merged into `master`, we know for certain that there is some commit (actually `H`, of course) after `F` that is a descendant of `F`—i.e., `F` is one of its parents—and also is an ancestor of `master`.  So:

```
git rev-list --ancestry-path --topo-order ^feature/X master
```

tells Git to list out commits `H`, `I`, and `J`, *and no other commits*.  That is, we won't go racing down the other commits brought in by merge `I`: those commits will get pruned.

If we then discard all but the last commit (with `tail -1` again), and optionally speed things up a bit with `--merges` to discard any non-merges even before using `tail`, that will let us locate commit `H` even if `I` or `J` is a merge:

```
H=$(git rev-list --ancestry-path --topo-order \
    --merges ^feature/X master | tail -1)
git rev-list ^$H^..feature/X
```

This is a hybrid of the two methods: we use `--ancestry-path` to find commits starting from `H`, and `tail -1` to drop all *but* commit `H`, then use `^$H^` to exclude commit-`G`-and-earlier.